# Как в python создать объект класса через метод

Tags: python, ооп, классы

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.bark = False

    def sound(self):
        self.bark = True
        return 'Woof'


mops = Dog.sound('Boba')    # Нужно создать объект таким образом
print(mops)
```

Comment: сначала вы определите объект класса `mops = Dog("Boba")` и только потом вызывайте методы которые опредлены. `mops.sound()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно возвращать из метода, меняющего состояние, сам объект. Предварительно создать объект, и потом поменять его свойство:

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.bark = False

    def sound(self) -> Dog:
        self.bark = True
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {'barking' if self.bark else 'silent'}"

smalldog = Dog('Fluffy')
print(smalldog)

mops = Dog('Boba').sound() # создаём объект, потом меняем свойство
print(mops)
```

Вывод:

```
Fluffy silent
Boba barking
```

Но можно сделать и с тем вызовом, как вы хотите, тогда придётся создавать объект прямо в методе, если я не путаю, такой подход называется "фабрика объектов":

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.bark = False

    def sound(name: str) -> Dog:
        dog = Dog(name)
        dog.bark = True
        return dog

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {'barking' if self.bark else 'silent'}"

smalldog = Dog('Fluffy')
print(smalldog)

mops = Dog.sound('Boba') # сразу создаём объект с нужным свойством
print(mops)
```

Вывод:

```
Fluffy silent
Boba barking
```

Comment: Желательно еще метод sound пометить как `@staticmethod`, чтобы он одинаково работал и от класса и от объекта.

Comment: @insolor С этим я ещё не разбирался, как это работает, надо будет как-нибудь разобраться